# Program IBAction Button To Turn Map Layer ON/OFF

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, ios6, logic

I'm using a IBAction button to turn a map layer on. This code turns it on when the button is tapped.

```
- (IBAction)lightingLayer:(id)sender {

[_mapView addTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];

}
```

Now I'd like to adjust it so when the user taps it once, the layers turns on. And when it's tapped again, it turns on and so forth. I took a stab at it by borrowing code from a similar example but it doesn't work.

```
- (IBAction)lightingLayer:(id)sender {

_Bool *isON = NULL; 

isON = !isON;

if(isON) {

[_mapView addTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];

} else {

[_mapView removeTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];

}
```

This flags, incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning bool from int. Can someone provide some simple code to help me achieve my goal. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error it's because you are assigning a bool value to a pointer. A pointer is nothing but a integer value, which holds a memory position as a hexadecimal number.

But actually, to accomplish what you want, you don't need a pointer, just use a property to store this bool and create a toggle funcionality.

declare this private property:

```
@property (strong, assign) BOOL isChecked;
```

And in your action:

```
- (IBAction)lightingLayer:(id)sender {

    self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;

    if(self.isChecked) {

        [_mapView addTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];

    } else {

         [_mapView removeTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];
    }
}
```

Ps: I only focused here in explain the error you are getting now. This add/remove tile logic is probably wrong too. I think you still would have to save the same reference to be added and later removed.

Comment: Yes, I need to fix my removeTileSource call first before I can run this. Looks correct, I'll follow up with an answer soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Do this way

```
BOOL isON;
- (IBAction)lightingLayer:(id)sender {
if(isON) {

    [_mapView addTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];
    isON=NO;

} else {

    [_mapView removeTileSource:[[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"MapID"]];
    isON=YES;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll follow up with an answer asap.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I went with. It's a slight adjustment from Lucas' answer. This will alternate turning the map on an off. Thanks for the responses.

```
//.h

@property BOOL *isChecked;


//.m

self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;

if((self.isChecked)) {

[_mapView addTileSource:onlineSource atIndex:1];

} else {

[_mapView setHidden:YES forTileSourceAtIndex:1  ];
```